# Colimits in the category of smooth manifolds

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

In the category of smooth real manifolds, do all small colimits exist? In other words, is this category small-cocomplete? I can see that computing push-outs in the category of topological spaces of smooth manifolds need not be manifolds, but this is not a proof.

Comment: Shouldn't "More generally" be "In other words" and "small-complete" be "small-cocomplete"?

Comment: I suppose you are correct. I was under the impression that "small-complete" was abused to mean all small limits and colimits existed. I've edited the question to reflect the change. 

Comment: If you require second countability in your definition of manifold then you might be in trouble. I guess if you try to take the coproduct of a point with itself over a huge cardinal you should end up with something not second countable. (What I've written is not a proof though)

Comment: @John - For this reason second countable is not a good requirement. It is better to require paracompact, which is alos a local property, unlike second countable. Each *component* of a paracompact manifold will be second countable, but there may be arbitrarily  many components.

Comment: I'm requiring paracompact but not second couontable in my definition, in case anybody was wondering. 

Comment: Also, note that some of the colimits that *do* exist in **Man** are different from the corresponding colimits taken in **Top**.

Comment: I have to take back my assertion that paracompact is a *local* condition. It is not quite a local condition, it turns out. Sorry for that. It is still preferable to second countable though, as everything you want to use second countable for really only depends on paracompact.

Comment: Agreed, paracompact is preferable. Thanks for that! Of course, I should have thought of the line with two origins! (either paracompactness/second-countability or hausdorfness had to fail...)

Comment: (I like to think of paracompactness as being a bridge between local and global.  It says that we can find a neighbourhood of each point intersecting only a finite number in our cover, that's a local condition, but it also says that we can do this simultaneously over the whole space, that's a global condition.)

Comment: Is it true that all small limits exist?

Comment: Colin, see the answers below!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd like to recast Reid's (excellent) answer slightly.  The essence of it is the following principle:

> To show that a limit or colimit doesn't exist in some category, embed your category in one where limits or colimits do exist and find some diagram in the original category whose colimit in the larger category does not lie in the image of the embedding.

The point is, it's usually much easier to show that an object $X$ of $\mathcal{D}$ is not an object of $\mathcal{C}$ than it is to show that $\mathcal{C}$ has nothing that looks like $X$.  For a simpler analogy, think of the difference between proving that $(0,1)$ is not complete versus proving that $(0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not closed.  The essence is the same, but the latter always seems to me to be a lot easier to grasp.

Back to the principle.  As stated, it's not quite strong enough.  You need a condition on the embedding:

> Make sure that your embedding preserves those limits or colimits that already exist.

Again, by analogy: to prove that a metric space $X$ is not complete, we need a **continuous** map from $X$ to a complete space with non-closed image.  An arbitrary map won't do.

Back to the case in hand.  As the functor $M \mapsto C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ is a (contravariantly) representable embedding, it preserves colimits and so is suitable for the argument to go through.

However, it does not preserve limits so if you asked the corresponding question about limits, you'd need a different embedding.  It turns out, though, that there is a complete and cocomplete category in which the category of manifolds embeds preserving all limits and colimits.  That is the category of [Hausdorff Froelicher spaces](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Froelicher+space).  Froelicher spaces may feel a little more topological than algebras so for those who, like myself, prefer topology to algebra, here's a recasting of Reid's answer using (Hausdorff) Froelicher spaces.

The key thing is that a Froelicher space is completely determined by either the smooth functions from it to $\mathbb{R}$ or the smooth curves in it (i.e. smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}$).

We take the same colimit: the pushout of

$$
\begin{matrix}
\{0\} &\to& \mathbb{R}\\
\downarrow \\
\mathbb{R}
\end{matrix}
$$

We shall show that it is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is clearly not a manifold.

Let us write the colimit as $X$.  First, we define a smooth function $F \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^2$.  It is the obvious one: it sends the first copy of $\mathbb{R}$ to the $x$-axis and the second copy to the $y$-axis.  As these two functions agree on $\{0\}$, this is a well-defined smooth function.

We want to show that this is an initial map.  One sufficient (but not necessary) condition for this is that every smooth function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ factors through $F$.

As Reid says, a smooth function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ consists of two smooth functions $f_1, f_2 \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f_1(0) = f_2(0)$.  Let $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $g(x,y) = f_1(x) + f_2(y) - f_1(0)$.  This is smooth and we have $g(x,0) = f_1(x) + f_2(0) - f_1(0) = f_1(x)$ and, similarly, $g(0,y) = f_2(y)$.  Thus $g \circ F = f$ and so every function $X \to \mathbb{R}$ factors through the inclusion $X \to \mathbb{R}^2$.  Hence the inclusion $X \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is initial.  Thus we can identify $X$ with its image, that being the union of the two axes.

As I said, this is merely a recasting of Reid's answer.  I post it partly to make it more topological in feel, but mainly to expose the general principle which Reid uses.

Comment: Andrew, this is a great explanation! Thank you for elaborating on the general method behind showing this; it reinforced my understanding of Reid's solution (which is very intriguing). Your method using Frölicher spaces is very nice. 

P.S.: I'm still slightly confused as to what goes into computing $dim_{\mathbb{R}} I^{n+1}/I^{n}$, but I think it might just take some elbow grease to get it to work. I hate to belabor the point, but if this computation isn't all that trivial, I'd appreciate a literature reference. If not, just ignore me! =) 



Comment: One of my reasons for recasting Reid's answer was that that step seemed very opaque to me as I don't think well "algebraically" about manifolds!  Once I'd worked out what was happening for myself, I figured it worth posting in case anyone else was like me.  So I can't give you a reference for that bit - you should ask Reid and Chris for that!

Comment: By "As the functor `$M\mapsto C^\infty(M)$` [...] preserves colimits and so is suitable for the argument to go through." you mean that it takes them to limits, right? Anyhow, +1 and thanks for making me wonder about Fröhlicher spaces.

Comment: Whoops!  Yes.  I suppose I could rescue it by considering it as a function in to C^infty-rings^OP.  There's probably some technical term for this property as well (a contravariant functor taking colimits to limits or vice-versa).

Comment: In my experience people usually say "the functor Man^op -> Ring preserves limits" and then there is a certain amount of head-scratching to figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: The calculation of the dimension of I^n/I^{n+1} is a standard part of the theory of jets and jet bundles. It is the dimension of the vector space of those functions which vanish up to order (n-1) modulo those which vanish up to order n. I first learned about this from the book "Stable Mappings and Their Singularities" by Golubitsky and Guillemin. I suspect that there are many other references out there, too. 

Comment: I know it's usually not good stile to comment something written 8 years ago, but I just wanted to mention that a "continuous" map from a metric space to a complete space with noncomplete image won't do. (For example the arctan function takes complete R to noncomplete open interval). So, you should take an isometric embedding (or a uniformly continuous embedding, since completeness is really a property of uniform spaces).

Answer (score 19):

I'll show that the pushout that glues two copies of $\mathbb{R}$ at the origin does not exist in **Man**.  Suppose for the sake of contradiction that it did; call the resulting manifold $M$, and the common image of the origins $x \in M$.  The real line $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring object in **Man**, and it represents the functor $X \mapsto C^\infty(X)$.  So, we learn that as a ring, $C^\infty(M)$ consists of pairs of functions on the real line with the same value at the origin.  Similarly we can identify the ideal $I$ in $C^\infty(M)$ of functions that vanish at $x$ with pairs of functions on the real line that both vanish at the origin.  Now we may compute that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} I^n/I^{n+1} = 2$ for all $n \ge 1$, which cannot happen for a point $x$ of a smooth manifold $M$.

Comment: Good solution. I was just about to post a more or less identical solution. The gist of this proof and several variations is that you can compute the ring of functions on a colimit by it universal property. You the combine this with the fact that the ring of functions determines the (smooth) manifold (at least in finite dimensions, but that is enough for a counter example). So if your ring of functions behaves poorly then you don't have a manifold. 

Comment: I understand your description of $C^{\infty}(M)$, but I am not following why $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} I^n/I^{n+1}=2$ gives us a contradiction. Can someone point me to a source which explains this? This looks good though! Thanks for the helpful discussion. 

Comment: When n=1, this condition implies that the tangent space at x is 2-dimensional. So if it were a manifold it would have to locally look like $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, an easy calculation shows that for the plane we have $dim_\mathbb{R} I^2/I^3 = 3$, generated by the 2-jets of the functions $x^2$, $xy$ and $y^2$. Choosing coordinates appropriately, the actual colimit has functions whose 2-jets are $x^2$ and $y^2$, but none with $xy$. 

Comment: Why did you consider I-adic filtration? Was that just an arbitrary approach to obtain a contradiction or was that somehow related to my imagination of $X$ that it should look like the tangent cone of a cusp at its singularity?

Comment: Hi Reid and Chris,
I've finally worked out exactly what you mean with this proof. It is very nice! Thanks very much. 
Best,
Glen